# MethodNotAllowedHttpException Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5, httpexception

I couldn't update or delete, especially when i add Route::resource(....) in route file

> web.php (route file)

```html
Route::resource('home/activity','ActivityController');
```

> edit.blade.php

```html
{!!Form::model($activity,['action' => ['ActivityController@update',$activity->id]])!!}

<div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label('Type :') !!} {!! Form::text('type',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary">Editer</button>

{!!Form::close()!!}

<br>
{!!Form::open(['Methode'=>'Delete','action' => ['ActivityController@destroy',$activity->id]])!!}

  {!! Form::submit('Delete',['class'=> 'btn btn-danger']) !!} 

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

> model

```html
  protected $table ='activities';
 protected $fillable =['type']
```

> ActivityController

```html
    public function update($id,Request $request){
        $activity = activity::findOrFail($id);
        $activity->update($request->all());
        return redirect('/home/activity');
    }

    public function destroy($id){
       Activity::destroy($id);
       return redirect('/home/activity');
    }
```

**Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `Form::open()` uses `post` method request. But when you create a Route::resource(), the update method takes a put or patch request.

So for a `put` or `patch` request you need to pass additional parameter as:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('activity.edit',$activity->id), 'method' => 'put')) }}
```

Same goes for delete form as:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('activity.delete',$activity->id), 'method' => 'delete')) }}
```